# Use an already trained neuronal network?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have an already trained neuronal network consisting of files NNbiases_b1.csv,  NNbiases_out.csv,  NNweights_h1.csv and NNweights_out.csv. The input and output layer sizes are known too.

Now I'm looking for a Python script that uses this neuronal network, means outputs data dependent on input data and trained network.

But whenever I google for an related script, I only find howtos and explanations about training an network!

So my question: when I have an already trained network with the data/files above: how can I use this neuronal network?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm definitely not qualified to answer this, but if you want someone else to, you'll need to be more specific. Where did you get these csv files, and what do they look like? Also, what are you trying to do? Categorize images? Generate some kind of text? And how does the keras tag apply to this? Are you wanting to do this in keras, or were these files generated with keras?  All of this will affect the answer.

Comment: @Addison both the input and output data are just floating point numbers. The data come from Keras, so I would guess this is also the easiest way to use it for my application too. They contain - as the names say - weights_h1, biases_b1, weights_out and biases_out data as  generated by Keras

Comment: @Addison to clarify this: the CSV-files contain the results which are delivered by model.get_weights()

Comment: If you want to save the model weights in Keras you should be using ```model.save_weights()```. This will save it as a HDF5 file that you can easily load. Loading these values from a csv file will have to be done manually. Using ```model.save()``` is even easier as it saves the model structure too.

Comment: @KurtisStreutker OK, and to come back to my original question: how can I use a model which was saved in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reconstruct your model's architecture, and then manually set the weights of each layer with something like that :

```
all_weights = []
NNweights_h1 = [...] #load your csv of weights
NNbiases_b1 = [...] #load your csv of biases

all_weights.append(NNweights_h1)
all_weights.append(NNbiases_b1)

model.layers[i].set_weights(all_weights)
```

And do that for all your layers.

## Update after precisions

In order to use your model (dummy exemple) :

- Reconstruct the architecture :

  ```py
  def model(model_input):


      x = Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu')(model_input)
      x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

      model = Model(model_input, x, name='Your_model')

      return model
  ```
- Instanciate it :

  ```py
  X_test = [...] #load your data
  input_shape = [...] #your test data shape
  model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
  model = model(model_input)
  ```
- Manually set the weights with using the code at the begining of the answer
- Use this model to predict your data:

  ```py
  prediction = model.predict(X_test)  #get the predictions of your model
  ```

I hope this will help you !

Comment: OK, this answers the question of loading the neuronal network - but how can I use it? Means how can I apply my input data and where do I get the result out of them?